# can't get text from clipboard | c#

Tags: c#

It doesn't show me anything inside the `logBox`, it just stays blank

```
namespace Clipboard_Logger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.TextLength;
            logBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
                    logBox.Text = logBox.Text + Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text) + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Triniox. While its great that you've included your code you should also include a brief description of the results you are seeing. Are you getting exceptions thrown? Failure to compile? Or just nothing happening?

Comment: it doesn't show me anything, it stays blank

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a background thread ( `BackGroundWorker.DoWork` ) to access controls on the UI thread. **Controls can only be accessed from the UI thread.**

Try adding a `BackGroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event and access your control from that. `ProgressChanged` runs from the UI thread.

**Edit** from your comment:

No, that's not what I meant, your're creating a new backgroundworker, you should use the existing one, like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1);
}
```

Also, you need to copy text to the clipboard.

Comment: You need to call BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(1) from the DoWork eventhandler.